# Matlab - Update limits of caxis with set()

Tags: matlab, colorbar

```
figure
surf(peaks)

colorbar;
h = caxis;
```

I want to update the limits of caxis. I know that this can be done by `caxis([cmin cmax])`. But assuming I have multiple figures, this only works by setting the current figures.

According to [MATLAB's Documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html#d119e100204), the property name is `limits`, but `set(h, 'limits', [-1 1])` throws me an error (*'Invalid or deleted object'*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in one of the examples in the documentation, what you want to do here is use the `target` input to the `caxis` function. `limits` is an input argument, not a property that can be used with `set`.

Your example then becomes:

```
figure;
surf(peaks);
h = gca;
colorbar;
caxis(h,[-1 1]);
```

Or alternatively, if you will be creating many plots before setting limits,

```
figure;
h = axes;
surf(peaks);
colorbar;
caxis(h,[-1 1]);
```

Comment: couldn't when I posted as was mobile, so was working from the documentation alone. fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

`limits`, as per official documentation, is a two-elements vector containing a minimum and a maximum value, it is not to be intended as a property name:

> vector of the form [cmin cmax]

If you want to achieve this for all your existing figures at once, you could find all the existing axes and apply the same limits to all of them:

```
% Before Matlab R2014b, 0 must be used instead of groot!
all_axes = findall(groot,'Type','axes');
caxis(all_axes,[-10 10]);
```